# Moq Error : Moq.MockVerificationException: The following setups were not matched

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

I wanna test my method with mock but it throw this exception. My class is this (this class do some simple actions on a file as though unzipping the file) :

```
public class FileActions
    {
        public virtual void Decompress(FileInfo fileInfo, DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileInfo.FullName, directoryInfo.FullName);
        }

        public virtual FileInfo GetConvertedFileToZip(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                var changeExtension = Path.ChangeExtension(fileInfo.FullName, "zip");
                File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, changeExtension);
                return new FileInfo(changeExtension);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }

        }
    }
```

and this is my test :

```
public void TestMockedMethodForNotNull()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<FileActions>();

        var fInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\ZipFiles\elmah.nupkg");
        mock.Setup(s => s.GetConvertedFileToZip(fInfo)).Verifiable();
        mock.VerifyAll();
    }
```

So, why does it get this Error :

> Moq.MockVerificationException: The following setups were not matched:
>   FileActions2 s => s.GetConvertedFileToZip(D:\ZipFiles\elmah.nupkg)

Comment: You class which mock is "FileActions", What is "FileActions2" ?

Comment: Yes but it was my Mistake when i were writing my question. It is not important. So, why do i get this Error?

Comment: Thanks yes realised it was mistake :) answered your question below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several issues with your Unit Test. I will only highlight the mocking side of things, as it relevant to the question you ask. Also your question has refer to "FileActions2", and I think this
a mistake when you originally add the question.

You Test:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void TestMockedMethodForNotNull()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<FileActions>();

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\ZipFiles\elmah.nupkg");

        mock.Setup(s => s.GetConvertedFileToZip(fileInfo)).Verifiable();

        mock.VerifyAll();
    }
```

The way you have written this test, Moq won't verify on GetConvertedFileToZip
This test fail fundamentally because Moq cannot provide an override for a virtual method GetConvertedFileToZip. You must create a proxy i,e mock.Object.

If you modify your test in such a way so your SUT (Sysytem Under Test), consumes an instance of the mocked object/proxied object
your verify would work partially (partially means you are heading right direction). Still something else to fix which I have described below.

Assuming your SUT is like below

```
public class Sut
{
    public void Do(FileActions fileActions)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\ZipFiles\elmah.nupkg");
        var s = fileActions.GetConvertedFileToZip(fileInfo);
    }
}
```

Your Test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMockedMethodForNotNull()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<FileActions>();

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\ZipFiles\elmah.nupkg");

        mock.Setup(s => s.GetConvertedFileToZip(fileInfo)).Verifiable();

        var sut = new Sut();

        sut.Do(mock.Object);


        mock.VerifyAll();
    }
```

This would produce an exception. This is because fileInfo you have setup on does not match the verification, when invoke via the Sut.

If you were to modify this test as below, this would succeed

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMockedMethodForNotNull()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<FileActions>();

        //var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\ZipFiles\elmah.nupkg");

        mock.Setup(s => s.GetConvertedFileToZip(It.IsAny<FileInfo>())).Verifiable();

        var sut = new Sut();

        sut.Do(mock.Object);

        mock.VerifyAll();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately i have no enough point to vote up your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, you might be a new user and in case if you are not aware, if this answer is sufficient, you can mark it as the answer for your question. this way others would know the correct answer. Just click on the tick. Thanks for your comments anyway :)

Comment: I am not a new user.I have been stackoverflow's member since 2008 but i decided to change my account and connect with my google account,therefore i am a new user by my new account. :)